# Hibernate: ERROR: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

I am new to SQL and Hibernate and I need help with the following:

Entity Product has (OneToMany) Entity Category which has some options (List).
I want when saving a Product this to be saved if not already existing, otherwise to be updated. Also, when saving a product I need to save the Category if the Category does not exist. When deleting/updating a Product the Category should not be deleted/updated.

When I tried to have a @GeneratedValue for Category id, each time I run the app, the Products were updated, but the Categories were re-inserted(with different id, without deleting the previous ones). 
I then tried the below code (having the Category name as @Id since I know that the name is unique) but then I get the errors you see.

What do I do wrong? I have searched Google and stackoverflow but I could not find a suitable/plain enough solution.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

…

```
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup create-drop-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- dbcp connection pool configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>

        <mapping class="main.Category" />
        <mapping class="main.Product" />

        <mapping class="main.Warehouse" />
```

...

Product Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private int pid;
    private String pName;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true )
    private List<Category> categories;
```

Category Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id 
    private Integer catid;
    private String cname;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String>
```

public class MainApp {

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> options1 = new ArrayList();
    options1.add("option11");
    options1.add("option12");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> options2 = new ArrayList();
    options2.add("option21");
    options2.add("option22");

    Category cat1 = new Category();
    cat1.setCatid(1);
    cat1.setCname("cat1");
    cat1.setcOptions(options1);

    Category cat2 = new Category();
    cat2.setCatid(2);
    cat2.setCname("cat2");
    cat2.setcOptions(options2);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Category> categories1 = new ArrayList<>();
    categories1.add(cat1);
    categories1.add(cat2);

    Product product1 = new Product();
    product1.setPid(1);
    product1.setpName("prod1");
    product1.setCategories(categories1);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Category> categories2 = new ArrayList<>();
    categories2.add(cat1);

    Product prod2 = new Product();
    prod2.setPid(2);
    prod2.setpName("prod2");
    prod2.setCategories(categories2);

    Warehouse w1 = new Warehouse(1, "s1");
    Warehouse w2 = new Warehouse(2, "s2");

    boolean saveWarehouse = true;
    boolean testAdd = true;
    boolean testDel = false;
    sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

        if (testAdd) {
            saveProduct(product1);
            saveProduct(prod2);
        }
        if (testDel) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(prod2);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
        if (saveWarehouse) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(w1);
            session.saveOrUpdate(w2);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("PROCESS COMPLETED");
}

public static void saveProduct(Product p) {
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(p);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

}

To save space, Getters & Setters omitted.

The output:

```
Hibernate: alter table Product_Category drop constraint UK_4ipwbaqj6eduy9ca1yi22afph
Hibernate: alter table Product_Category add constraint UK_4ipwbaqj6eduy9ca1yi22afph unique (categories_cname)
Hibernate: select product_.pid, product_.pName as pName2_2_ from Product product_ where product_.pid=?
Hibernate: select category_.cname from Category category_ where category_.cname=?
Hibernate: select category_.cname from Category category_ where category_.cname=?
Hibernate: delete from Product_Category where Product_pid=?
Hibernate: delete from Category_cOptions where Category_cname=?
Hibernate: delete from Category_cOptions where Category_cname=?
Hibernate: insert into Product_Category (Product_pid, categories_cname) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Product_Category (Product_pid, categories_cname) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Category_cOptions (Category_cname, cOptions) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Category_cOptions (Category_cname, cOptions) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Category_cOptions (Category_cname, cOptions) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Category_cOptions (Category_cname, cOptions) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select product_.pid, product_.pName as pName2_2_ from Product product_ where product_.pid=?
Hibernate: select category_.cname from Category category_ where category_.cname=?
Hibernate: insert into Product (pName, pid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Product_Category (Product_pid, categories_cname) values (?, ?)
Mar 16, 2019 4:08:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 23505
Mar 16, 2019 4:08:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'UK_4IPWBAQJ6EDUY9CA1YI22AFPH' defined on 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY'.
Mar 16, 2019 4:08:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Mar 16, 2019 4:08:17 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1490)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:515)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3348)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2519)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at main.MainApp.saveProduct(MainApp.java:96)
    at main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:72)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1340)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1484)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.DerbySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'UK_4IPWBAQJ6EDUY9CA1YI22AFPH' defined on 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'UK_4IPWBAQJ6EDUY9CA1YI22AFPH' defined on 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't use a functional name is ID. This will prevent you to modify the name of a category. IDs must be unique, but also immutable. If a category already exists, then the user should typically select it among a chice of category, and it will thus have an ID already. If he creates one, then it won't have any ID.

Comment: "This will prevent you to modify the name of a category". This is a good point! Thank you. But when I use auto-generated id, I have the problem I mentioned: "When I tried to have a @GeneratedValue for Category id, each time I run the app, the Products were updated, but the Categories were re-inserted(with different id, without deleting the previous ones). "

Comment: If the categgories were reinserted, it means you told Hibernate to do that, by passing categories without ID, but with the same name as actual, existing categories. If an entity without an ID is saved with Hibernate, Hibernate considers it needs to be inserted, since it doesn't have an ID yet.

Comment: No, this is not the case. As I said, I had :  @ Id @ GeneratedValue
 private Integer id;      So, Id always existed. The problem was that although the categories are the same, each time I run the app a new id is created, so Hibernate inserts again the same categories with different Ids (the ones auto-generated). You can see what i had as id in the code since I have commented out.

Comment: The **class** defines a property which is an auto-generated ID. If the **object** that you save has a null id (i.e. doesn't have an ID, in English), then Hibernate considers that it doesn't exist in the database yet, and thus inserts it.

Comment: EDIT: I edited the code to show the original approach. Now the Category class has its own id which is always provided (in the main class). Nevertheless, I get again the same error: Caused by: ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'UK_TFE67LU42TN7D0PEWNWK4QY0' defined on 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY'. Inspecting the database, I see that the PRODUCT-CATEGORY has 2 indexes on CAEGORIES-CATID. I am not sure if this is normal! The problem arises when saving the second PRODUCT

Comment: FIX? Experimenting, just changing the @ OneToMany to @ ManyToMany, the problem is solved!!! Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Because you told hibernate that it was okay to have multiple connections between the objects, in other words you told it that your objects weren't unique.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception on exactly the same data-base vendor.
The  culprit was this line:

```
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private int fieldName = -1;
```

So that, it enforced the DB attribute to be unique, when the incoming data
did not satisfy this constraint.
In this case, it has to be set to:

```
unique = false
```